# xmlstarlet, change xmlnodes, given a list of identifier nodes

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have used xmlstarlet, for the following

replacement:
xmlstarlet ed -u //author[text()='Gambardella, Matthew'] -v 'Gambardella' bookstore.xml, in the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
```

How can i, instead of a search and replace process, set specifically the values, in an xml file, using the book id identifier?

For example, for the  book id="bk101", and for book id="bk103" the author node, must become Gambardella, no matter what it now has (so we do not search and replace, but we set the value), for book id="bk102", the author must be set to say Clems Lebof. So we provide some comma separated book id values, and the corresponding values we need to be set, so the output will eventually become:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Clems Lebof</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Gambardella</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
```

How could the above, be accomplished, with the use of xmlstarlet?

Answer (score 0):

Change the XPath to match `author` elements that is child of `book` where `id` attribute equals either 'bk101' or 'bk103' :

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//book[@id='bk101' or @id='bk103']/author" -v 'Gambardella' bookstore.xml
```

Comment: and a tip, for making this for multiple, sequential replacements? How can i run the above command, many times, say i had to do 1000 replacements, like the above example? Should i make a bash script, that consists of 1000 commands like the above? Or can i use input files, for teh book ids, and their corresponding authors replacements?

Comment: it is my mistake, @har07 but the most important part of my question, was how one could make the above scale, for example what if the above command, should run for a 1000 replacements? Something like we have 1000 groups of ids group1: (@id='bk101' or @id='bk103'..) group2 (@id='bk104' or @id='bk105'...) and for each of the above groups, a corresponding replacement value